# How to get the size of an arrowhead line in VSTO Addin?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

We are developing a Powerpoint VSTO Addin and need to programmatically calculate the real width and height of an Arrowhead in Powerpoint.
Our code may look like below:

```
freeFormShape.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = MsoArrowheadStyle.msoArrowheadTriangle;
freeFormShape.Line.EndArrowheadLength = MsoArrowheadLength.msoArrowheadShort;
freeFormShape.Line.EndArrowheadWidth = MsoArrowheadWidth.msoArrowheadNarrow;
```

Is there any way to know the size of End arrowhead triangle in points?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [LineFormat.Weight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.lineformat.weight) property which returns or sets the thickness of the specified line, in points.